# Java code will not quit when using -1 and numbers do not transfer to alphabetic grades

Tags: java, arrays

When using -1 to quit it does not work and also it does not turn the grades from numerical or alphabetic. This is just a simple grade book for a college class.

```
public class Assignment3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {`enter code here`
        // Defining the constants for min and max range
        final int minValue = -1;
        final int maxValue = 100;
       
        promptForInt(String message, int minValue,int maxValue);
        
    }
    
    public static void promptForInt(String message,int minValue,int maxValue)
    { 
        System.out.println(message);
        convertToLetter(double avg);

        // Declaring variables for inital value in the loop
        float sum = 0;
        int numStudents = 0;
        float score = 0;
        boolean doneYet = false;
        
      
        //Sentinel-controlled do-while loop, don't know how many times will run
        do
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter the score for student #%d" 
                    + "(or -1 to quit): ", numStudents);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            score = Float.parseFloat(keyboard.nextLine());
            
            if (score != -1)
            {
                sum += score;
                numStudents += 1;
            }
        }while (score != -1);
        double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;
        System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore
                + " which equates to a " + avg);
        
        do
        {
            // Input Validation
            if (score > minValue || score < maxValue)
            {
                System.err.printf("Invalid value. The acceptable range is"
                        + "between %d and %d\n"
                        + "Please try again\n",minValue, maxValue);  
            }
            else
            {
                doneYet = true;    
            }
        }while (doneYet == false);
    }
    
    public static void convertToLetter(double avg) 
    {
        // Identifying the ranges for the grade letter
        if (avg >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
        else if (avg >= 80)
        {
           System.out.println("B"); 
        }
          else if (avg >= 70)
        {
           System.out.println("C"); 
        }
          else if (avg >= 60)
        {
           System.out.println("D"); 
        }
          else
        {
           System.out.println("F"); 
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Start by moving `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` outside the loop so it only gets done once.  It may or may not make a difference, but either way it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix you function calls and call the `convertToLetter` after the user inputs scores.

Try this code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.io.*;

public class Assignment3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Defining the constants for min and max range
        final int minValue = -1;
        final int maxValue = 100;
        promptForInt("", minValue, maxValue);
        
    }
    
    public static void promptForInt(String message,int minValue,int maxValue)
    { 
        System.out.println(message);
        //convertToLetter(double avg);

        // Declaring variables for inital value in the loop
        float sum = 0;
        int numStudents = 0;
        float score = 0;
        boolean doneYet = false;
        
      
        //Sentinel-controlled do-while loop, don't know how many times will run
        do
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter the score for student #%d" 
                    + "(or -1 to quit): ", numStudents);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            score = Float.parseFloat(keyboard.nextLine());
            
            if (score != -1)
            {
                sum += score;
                numStudents += 1;
            }
        }while (score != -1);
        double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;
        convertToLetter(avgScore);
        System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore
                + " which equates to a " + avgScore);
        
        do
        {
            // Input Validation
            if (score > minValue || score < maxValue)
            {
                System.err.printf("Invalid value. The acceptable range is"
                        + "between %d and %d\n"
                        + "Please try again\n",minValue, maxValue);  
            }
            else
            {
                doneYet = true;    
            }
        }while (doneYet == false);
    }
    
    public static void convertToLetter(double avg) 
    {
        // Identifying the ranges for the grade letter
        if (avg >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
        else if (avg >= 80)
        {
           System.out.println("B"); 
        }
          else if (avg >= 70)
        {
           System.out.println("C"); 
        }
          else if (avg >= 60)
        {
           System.out.println("D"); 
        }
          else
        {
           System.out.println("F"); 
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was some logic error on your part. I have corrected the code.

This will convert the marks into grades and not run into any infinite loops too. Comment if you have any doubts.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Defining the constants for min and max range
        final int minValue = -1;
        final int maxValue = 100;
        promptForInt("", minValue, maxValue);
        
    }
    
    public static void promptForInt(String message,int minValue,int maxValue)
    { 
        System.out.println(message);
        //convertToLetter(double avg);

        // Declaring variables for inital value in the loop
        float sum = 0;
        int numStudents = 0;
        float score = 0;
        boolean doneYet = false;
        
      
        //Sentinel-controlled do-while loop, don't know how many times will run
        do
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter the score for student #%d" 
                    + "(or -1 to quit): ", numStudents);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            score = Float.parseFloat(keyboard.nextLine());
            
            if (score != -1)
            {
                sum += score;
                numStudents += 1;
            }
        }while (score != -1);
        double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;
        
        System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore
                + " which equates to a " + convertToLetter(avgScore));
        
        do
        {
            // Input Validation
            if (score < minValue || score > maxValue)
            {
                System.err.printf("Invalid value. The acceptable range is"
                        + "between %d and %d\n"
                        + "Please try again\n",minValue, maxValue);  
            }
            else
            {
                doneYet = true;    
            }
        }while (doneYet == false);
    }
    
    public static String convertToLetter(double avg) 
    {
        // Identifying the ranges for the grade letter
        if (avg >= 90)
        {
            return "A";
        }
        else if (avg >= 80)
        {
           return "B";
        }
          else if (avg >= 70)
        {
           return "C"; 
        }
          else if (avg >= 60)
        {
           return "D"; 
        }
          else
        {
           return "F";
        }
    }    
}
```